# VueJS and Cordova - cant retrieve the cordova instance in Vue components

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js

I am trying to develop a cordova android app that uses VueJS. I haven't used cordova before, so this might be a beginners mistake, although i am unable to find a solution. I am trying to call a method of a plugin i created from the root App.vue-component.

To set up the app i both tried to use [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@valeriocapogna/how-to-setup-a-cordova-app-using-vue-js-8ba1315b9666) and the [vue-cli-plugin-cordova package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-cordova). To create the plugin i followed [this guide](https://github.com/RootSoft/Create-a-custom-Cordova-plugin). I am able to build the application. When I'm trying to call the plugin using `cordova.execute` I get a 'cant call execute on undefined' error message.
The rest of the app is working as intended.

I've tried to:

- import the function from the my_plugin.js script in the www-folder within the plugin directory and calling it
- calling `cordova.execute(...)`
- calling `cordova.plugins.<plugin>.<method>(...)`
- using `document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);` as [seen here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) and then trying to call cordova within the callback function.

None of these succeeded. I used `npm run build`, `cordova build android` and `cordova run android --device` to build and run the app. `cordova plugins list` gives both the preinstalled whitelist-plugin aswell as my own:

```
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
mp3dl 0.0.1 "mp3dl"
```

However, in the config.xml-file only

```
...
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
...
```

is listed. I am unsure if this is an issue.

The import

```
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

in index.html is present.

Thanks alot in regards for any help or tips. If you need further information or file contents i will happily provide it.

Comment: Have you called `cordova.execute` inside the `yourCallbackFunction` ?

Comment: Ok. As I just saw, the JavaScript Interface only procides a `exec` function [Docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html#the-javascript-interface)